# sum of raster counts

Tags: arcpy

I'm trying to get the sum of "counts" in a raster. I have the code below which can successfully read the counts of each row in raster attribute and stores the counts in a list provided below.

> [763461] [407207] [232269] [137428] [83909] [55074] [33340] [24168]
>   [16747] [11488] [7010] [4323] [4021] [2552] [1497] [775] [72]

However, I want to get the sum of the counts. I am providing the code and error below.

code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#To overwrite output
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/Subhasis/Test/7-17-14/test"

#set local variables-STI extraction
inRaster ="sti"
inSQLClause = "VALUE >= 9"

#checkout ArcGIS spatial analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Execute ExtractByAttributes
attExtract = ExtractByAttributes(inRaster, inSQLClause) 

# Save the output 
attExtract.save("C:/Subhasis/Test/7-17-14/test/STI-9")

inraster ="sti-9"
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inraster,"","","Count","")

for row in rows:
    count = row.getValue("Count")
    s1=[]
    s1.append(count)
    print sum(range(s1))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Subhasis/Test/7-17-14/test/test.py", line 31, in <module>
    print sum(range(s1))
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got list.
```

Comment: please format your code appropriately using code blocks

Comment: Try `sum(s1)` instead of `sum(range(s1))`

Answer (score 4):

You keep on redefining s1 as an empty list for each iteration.

Try this instead:

```
s1 = []
for row in rows:
    s1.append(row.getValue("Count"))

print sum(s1)
```

Or:

```
counter = 0
for row in rows:
    counter += row.getValue("Count")

print counter
```

For bonus points, arcpy.da, utilizing a generator expression:

```
print sum(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inraster, ("Count")))
```

Comment: :Thanks a lot. I got the correct sum using your last code"print sum(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inraster, ("Count")))". Thank you everybody for your instant help!

Comment: @Inception, you should familiarize yourself with the data access module instead of the older cursors. Less code and it's faster.

Comment: @Inception Also when dealing with lists of lists it's worth familiarizing yourself with [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

Comment: @om_henners Thank you very much for providing the information!